# Horizontal div img alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have small problem trying to make my website look better.
The problem is that I'm trying to align images inside my div tag, horizontally. I have searched google and read other posts here, but none of them seemed to work for me. I've tried things like: float, margin, position:absolute, but none of them wanted to work, they just end up aligning in the center and going downwards, so I'm wondering if anybody has any solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

```css
<style>
    body {
      background-image: url('bakgrund.jpg');
    }

    #galleri { 
      width: 200px;
      display:block; 
      margin: auto;
    }

    .galleri img { 
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: .6;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .galleri img:hover { 
      opacity: 1;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="galleri" id="galleri" >
        <img src="mat1.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="avocado">
        <img src="mat2.JPG" width="250" height="250" alt="tapas" align="3">
        <img src="mat3.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="soft taco">

        <img src="mat5.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="hard taco" >
       <img src="rest1.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="restaurang">
        <img src="rest2.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="restaurang2">
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: To clarify your question, you want them 3 in a row? If not, try providing a picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: this is because you have set width of 'galleri' to 200px change that to `750px` and float the images to left

Comment: I got the help I needed, I wanted three in a row. There is an answer below.

Comment: kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/knh9spqg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this changes

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('bakgrund.jpg');
    }

    .galleri {
        display: block;
        margin: 30px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .galleri img { 
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: .6;
        margin: auto 30px;
    }

    .galleri img:hover { 
        opacity: 1;

    }

</style>

<body>
    <div class="galleri">
        <img src="mat1.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="avocado">
        <img src="mat2.JPG" width="250" height="250" alt="tapas" align="3">
        <img src="mat3.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="soft taco">
    </div>
    <div class="galleri">
        <img src="mat5.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="hard taco" >
        <img src="rest1.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="restaurang">
        <img src="rest2.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="restaurang2">
    </div>
</body>
```

you should make another  element for every 3 images

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks anyways, I'm gonna try and see if it has anything to do with not having a <ol> and <li> tag.

Comment: do you want 3 images in a row?